# Send angularJS value to MVC action

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a function in my MVC controller which downloads a file, I need it to do this when its passed a filename. This function works, but the file name is an AgularJS value.

MVC Method:

```
 public ActionResult DownloadFile()
 {
    string fileName = "test.txt";
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/UploadedFiles/";
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path + fileName);            
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
 }
```

This works when called using:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here to download", "DownloadFile", new { })
```

I need to pass a string to the method however to use as "fileName".

Updated Method to accommodate receiving fileName:

```
 public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
 {
   string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/UploadedFiles/";
   byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path + fileName);
   return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
 }
```

Ways I've tried calling this methods while passing an agular value are as follows:

1)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download File", "DownloadFile", new { id = "{{file}}" })
```

This way causes an exception in the method as "fileName" is null so the filepath doesn't resolve for the download.

2)

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Download File", "DownloadFile", "Home", new { id = "{{file}}" })
```

Practically the same as the fist, but specifying the controller name, gives same result as the first.

3)

```
@{
   var url = Url.Action( "DownloadFile2", "Home", new { id = "{{file}}" });
   url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
 }
<a data-ng-href="@url">Download File</a>
```

This results in the browser going to page with URL: http://localhost/Home/DownloadFile/test.txt with page error: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The view can see the value and can output it to the page as plain text, but I can't figure out how to send the value to the method.

Comment: Regarding the 3rd - the parameter is named `fileName` so it would need to be `new { fileName = "{{file}}"`

Comment: oh haha... Yeah it works now, I thought "id" was generic assignment for it to send it to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the following signature for your action:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
```

You should always send the parameter named `fileName` no matter if you're using `Url.Action` or `ActionLink`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download File", "DownloadFile", "Home", new { fileName = "{{file}}" })

var url = Url.Action( "DownloadFile2", "Home", new { fileName = "{{file}}" });
```

`id` is used as a generic parameter only when you define your supported routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    // Parameter defaults
);
```

There you can control if id can be optional or not and many other things.